# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError when build maven project with jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

try build java project with jenkins but got this error

```
maven35-agent.jar already up to date
maven35-interceptor.jar already up to date
maven3-interceptor-commons.jar already up to date
[apps] $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/java8/bin/java -cp /var/lib/jenkins/maven35-agent.jar:/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.5.x/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.5.x/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.5.x /var/lib/jenkins/remoting.jar /var/lib/jenkins/maven35-interceptor.jar /var/lib/jenkins/maven3-interceptor-commons.jar 38515
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: hudson/remoting/Launcher has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:401)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main.main(Maven35Main.java:135)
at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main.main(Maven35Main.java:65)
```

this is my pom.xml files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>test1</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.project.test1</groupId>
        <artifactId>test1-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>test1-parent</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <modules>
        <module>test1-dependencies</module>
    </modules>
```

for the java version is using jdk from jenkins global tools configuration

Comment: You running on an old java version

Comment: You are also running an old Maven version... current is 3.8.6 (https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)